# Somar a quantidade total de um produto com lote diferente? SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sum

Olá! Como vão? Espero que todos estejam bem!
Galera eu sou novo no ramo e acredito que meu problema seja fácil de solucionar, mas ainda não tenho conhecimento para resolver e desde já eu agradeço a todos pela ajuda!

Estou fazendo a consulta abaixo em uma tabela que retorna a quantidade de saída por produto e gostaria que essa quantidade fosse somada por produto, mas o problema é que nesta tabela pode ocorrer que, para o mesmo produto exista dois lotes, e quando isso ocorre o resultado retorna duas linhas, como posso fazer para que ele retorne apenas uma linha com a soma dos dois lotes do mesmo produto? Já tentei fazer subquery e XTAB, mas mesmo assim ele continua retornando a soma por lote e não por produto. O estranho é que no SELECT não coloque para retornar o lote

```
    SELECT  
        codigoestabelecimento,  
        tipodocumento,  
        seriedocumento,  
        documentosaida,  
        codigoproduto,  
        SUM(quantidadesaida) AS QUANTIDADESAIDA  
   FROM  
        lotesaida  
   WHERE  
        codigoestabelecimento = '1'  
        AND documentosaida = '1313'  
   GROUP BY  
        codigoestabelecimento,  
        tipodocumento,  
        seriedocumento,  
        documentosaida,  
        codigoproduto,  
        quantidadesaida
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  
        codigoestabelecimento,  
        tipodocumento,  
        seriedocumento,  
        documentosaida,  
        codigoproduto,  
        SUM(quantidadesaida) AS QUANTIDADESAIDA  
   FROM  
        lotesaida  
   WHERE  
        codigoestabelecimento = '1'  
        AND documentosaida = '1313'  
   GROUP BY  
        codigoestabelecimento,  
        tipodocumento,  
        seriedocumento,  
        documentosaida,  
        codigoproduto
```

O problema está no agrupamento, ele está agrupando pela quantidade também, anulando sua função agregadora `sum()` quando as quantidades são diferentes.
Se ainda retornar "duplicado" veja atentamente os valores dos campos que não foram agregados.

Comment: Amigo de fato o problema era exatamente isso, muito obrigado pela ajuda!